# Access 2010 development environment

Tags: ms-access

Newbie - Looking for assistance in moving an Access 2010 front end, SQL back end, from an isolated test environment to developing in a live environment with multiple developers.

Currently reading "Automatically Deploy a New Access Client" http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3286111/Automatically-Deploy-a-New-Access-Client.htm

Need assistance with how to switch from test database to live database during publishing.

Answer (score 0):

The general assumption is that on code start up, you need to check if the current linked back end is the same. This suggests that you need to have some .ini or text file that points to the production server.

Or if you on the same network, then you can simply use the linked table manager, point the front end to the production SQL server and re-link. You then compile to an accDE and simply distribute that pre-linked database to each workstation.

So you only really need re-link code on start-up **if** you can’t be on site or on the same network to pre-link.

If you link to SQL server using a FILE dsn, then Access automatically converts the links to DSN-less, and thus no re-linking code is required, nor is any “DSN” setup on each workstation required.

So you can manually switch and re-link your front end application before you distribute and that would means you simply switch which database the FE points to before you distribute.

As noted, if you can’t be on the same network for this “switch”, then you have to adopt some code to test the current link, and ensure that it points to the correct server (and this means an external file with the correct SQL server needs to exist).

If you need to switch during deployment, then you need some code to test if a re-link is required, and if yes, then you need some re-link code to run “one time” to correct and point the links to the production server. It certainly much less work to pre-link, and thus no switch or change in the connection and which SQL server you point to will be required during deployment.

If you need some re-link code, then this code can re-link for you:

http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html